# Returning updated objects with deleted keys

Tags: javascript, object, return, conditional-statements

I’m trying to return the updated version of this object, but I all I can seem to return is the original object. Here is what my code looks like:

```js
var nameOne = {"name":"ernest", "age":50, funky:false};

function ObjLoop(user) {
  for (var item in user){
    if(user[item] === false){
          delete user['item'];
           //return user;
        }
  }
  return user;
}
```

I've tried to return it within the if-statement as well, and I can’t get it to return it with just the age and name.

This might be a stupid fix, but I just can’t seem to figure out how to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting the property named `item`, not the property name stored in the variable `item`

```
delete user['item'];
```

You want

```
delete user[item];
```

Answer (score 0):

In `delete user['item']`, you are deleting a property by the name of `item` in the object referenced by `user`. You don't need quotes, since you want to delete the property you're currently iterating on, whose name (or *key*) is the *value* of `item` and not `'item'` itself.

```
delete user[item];
```

Answer (score 0):

`delete user['item'] // deletes "item" in user object . which does not exists;`

```
delete user[item]; // just removes quotes round your key.
```